# Facebook API chat client

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Since the [Facebook Chat XMPP support](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat) ends on April 30th 2015, I am currently thinking of an alternative way to access Facebook Chat.

Getting [inbox](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/inbox) content or receiving a specific [message](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/message) works well using Facebook's Graph API, but to create a working chat client there is need of another two points:

For once, a chat client needs to be able to send chat messages. This should include responding to an existing [thread](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/thread) as well as creating new threads (starting a new group conversation etc.).

Then, polling for new messages is ugly. The chat client needs to receive notifications when a new message is being received, similar to [GitHub Hooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/). A Facebook App may receive some kind of [real-time updates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.3#subscribefields), but an *on_message_receive* event is currently missing.
Some *receive_message_notifications* permission would also be handy, to be able to use a routing server which sends the message ID to the client via webhooks, without having to grant it *mailbox_read* access.

Is there something I have overlooked, are there any alternatives not being tagged as deprecated, or is there (currently) no support for an open chat API?

Comment: No there is nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you will try, it will definitely not be allowed. There are no alternatives for the Chat API.

There is only the new Messenger Platform with a separate App Store for the Facebook Messenger: https://messenger.com/platform

You can´t create your own Messenger with access to the Facebook chat anymore.